# How to get the absolute path of a File in a Bazel action?

Tags: bazel

I am interacting with a tool in a Bazel action that requires absolute paths. I cannot use a relative path without modifying the tool.

How can I get the absolute path of `File` in Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great way of doing this in a Bazel rule. But this is the workaround I've used when in a similar situation. You essentially create a wrapper script that converts relative to absolute paths.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/my/tool $(readlink -f $1)
```

You could of course use other `ctx.actions.expand_template` to generate your wrapper script dynamically as well.